# Найти позднюю из дат

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть пандас дата фрейм с 2 столбцами дат: df.date1 и df.date2. Как добавить столбец содержащий более позднюю из этих дат?

Comment: Что-то типа `df['max_date'] = df[['date1','date2']].max(axis=0)`, хотя может быть `axis=1`, я точно не помню.

Comment: @CrazyElf `axis=1` (по строкам).

Answer (score 2):

Примените метод `.max()` к вашему датафрейму:

```
df['later'] = df.max(axis='columns')
```

---

Пример:

```
>>> df
```

> ```
>        date1      date2
> 0 2012-05-01 2012-05-03
> 1 2012-05-04 2012-05-02
> ```

```
>>> df['later'] = df.max(axis='columns')
>>> df
```

> ```
>        date1      date2      later
> 0 2012-05-01 2012-05-03 2012-05-03
> 1 2012-05-04 2012-05-02 2012-05-04
> ```